# How to join multiple text columns in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

How can i merge/join multiple text columns within a single pandas dataframe
without concatenating the columns individually

e.g

```
d = pd.DataFrame({'A':['one','two','three'],'B':['London','New York','Tokyo'],'C':['UK','USA','Japan'],'D':['Hot','Hot','Cold']})
```

the output should be

```
0         one London UK Hot
1      two New York USA Hot
2    three Tokyo Japan Cold
Name: combined, dtype: object
```

Comment: The problem with using concat here is that i need to mention column names individually.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) along `axis=1` with `join`:

```
d.apply(' '.join, axis=1)

0         one London UK Hot
1      two New York USA Hot
2    three Tokyo Japan Cold
dtype: object
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. Thanks a lot :)